# foreach iteration after Select

Tags: c#, linq

Can anyone explain this behaviour ?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var models = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(x => new Model { Id = x.ToString() });

        foreach (var model in models)
        {
            model.Data = $"{model.Id} Data bla";
        }

        foreach (var model in models)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{model.Id} | {model.Data}");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Model
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

Output :

0 |

1 |

2 |

However, if I call ToList() after the Select, my output changes to:

0 | 0 Data bla

1 | 1 Data bla

2 | 2 Data bla

I've tried putting a breakpoint in each of the foreach blocks and called

```
models.Any(x=>x.Equals(model))
```

but always returns false without the ToList() call

Comment: `.Select()` doesn't materialize its results until enumerated. The first `foreach` changes a bunch of `new Model {}` objects, the second `foreach` works on a brand new set of `new Model {}` objects. The `.ToList()` materializes it once and for all.

Comment: but doesn't the foreach block itself enumerate through the models ?

Comment: Of course it does -- but each block enumerates through its *own* set of models. The first `foreach` may as well not have happened because the results are never used.

Comment: @StefanKovacs: Without the `ToList` its like you replace every instance of `models` with `Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(x => new Model { Id = x.ToString() })` because Select doesn't generate the items, it just provides code that allows them to be generated. When you iterate over models it runs that code to generate the items every time. It doesn't record or cache them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`models` is a sequence that gets populated with new instances of `Model` each time you iterate over it. I.e. you get a new set of instances every time you foreach over it.

When you call `ToList()` you capture a copy of one of the iterations and all the instances which can then be modified.

Comment: Indeed, I added a new field to the Model object:

`public string Guid = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();`

and doing a Console.WriteLine with the model.Id and model.Guid.
the models in the first foreach have different Guids than the models in the second foreach

Thank you!

Comment: @StefanKovacs FYI - you could have also looked at `.GetHashCode()` thats the more common way to check if its the same object